# Performance issues drawing PolyLines in Android Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-volley

I have a few doubts about drawing a polylines on a `MapFragment`.

Should I draw them in separate layer like `TileOverlay` or `GroundOverlay`, is it possible at all? 
I want to achieve good performance, as good as possible. Now I have a map fragment where I receive using `Volley` library some data from external server and in `AsyncTask` I draw every polyline separately in loop. Should I use `AsyncTask` for this? `Volley` requests working asynchronous I suppose, but in callback which is invoking by success listener where I invoke drawing polylines this work in the same thread what the main activity so I put this to `AsyncTask`.

I have list of polylines data and method where in loop I draw every polyline on the map:

```
  mMap.clear();
            for (PolyLineDTO polyLineDTO : currentPolyLines) {
                polyLines.add(drawPolyline(polyLineDTO));
            }
```

Method `drawPolyline(polyLineDTO)` just invoking `mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions)`.

When I have about 500 polylines drawn on the map, it noticeably slows.

What do you think?

Comment: Try splitting every issue in a separate question, posting relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks. I've splitted every issue and I've added more description.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to rethink your design choice.

If you add 500 lines to show them on a small screen like phone's, you won't see the map.

If most of them are outside of the screen, don't add them until user scrolls there. Just calculate each `Polyline`'s `LatLngBounds` and only add them when it intersects with `getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds`.

And don't use `AsyncTask`s when you use `Volley`. Calls to `GoogleMap`'s and other API v2 objects function must be done on the UI thread.

Comment: So drawing the polylines must be done in the UI thread? I use polyline to mark traffic on streets so I use them to color the streets. One polyline correspond to the segments of street. If the street is straight it has one polyline, but if not, it has to have more polylines. I use visible region, if I not use it I would be forced to display tens of thousands of polylines for a single city even if user would see only a part of them.

Comment: Referring to my question about overlays. Can I add all of the polylines at once to the map or I'm forced to add them separately in the loop?